Error al instalar los paquetes "dlib" y "face-recognition" en Python versión 3.12
ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 24.0
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
Igualmente para face-recognition

Hola Gabriel, bienvenido a [es.so]. El error es bastante explícito... ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib... CMake es necesario para construir el paquete desde  las fuentes. ¿Has probado a instalar  CMake previamente? Asegúrate también de que CMake  esté agregado al PATH

dlib es una biblioteca de C++ con binding para Python, necesita por tanto ser compilada previamente. Dado que usas Windows, hasta Python 3.6 dlib proporcionaba binarios precompilados para Windows pero ya no. face-recognition es un paquete puro de Python, pero tiene a dlib como requisito... En definitiva, dado que tienes que compilar dlib necesitas configurar tu sistema para poder hacerlo, necesitas instalar Cmake y seguramente instalar/actualizar Visual  Studio  C++.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
